# Why programs developed using incremental approach are difficult to maintain?

Tags: development-process

I am confused , Why Software that are developed using the evolutionary approach are harder to be maintained ?

Comment: There is a ton of context missing here.

Comment: This is just a direct question that i have been asked in my exam

Comment: They’re not harder to maintain... I’m confused.

Comment: Well, you're using two different words here: *incremental* and *evolutionary* mean two very different things.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed: "*This is just a direct question that i have been asked in my exam*" What did your teacher tell you during class? That's likely the answer they want. Without having sat in on the class, its impossible to know how to answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mostly because you frequently come up against design decisions where the easiest way to add a new feature to an existing program differs from the best way you would make everything if you were starting from scratch. That doesn't mean it is necessarily more difficult to maintain, but you have to make a concerted effort to continually refactor as you go along, and not everyone is conscientious enough to do so.

Comment: This happens to me **>>a lot<<** And I wouldn't call it  "conscientious" (or lack thereof). Just not enough time to get the job done on schedule, and to get it done right (meaning the way I'd like to do it). Clients always (almost always) get additional ideas in their heads during the course of any non-trivial new development project. And that's to be expected -- even welcomed. It usually results in an overall better product, even if the implementation is bags-on-bags spaghetti code. If it's a good enough product, time will (maybe) eventually be made available to refactor it right, maybe v2.0